# Regex too have certain letters and at least one of a certain group of letters

Tags: java, regex, search, letter

Can someone help me with a regex statement for finding a statement using this rule?

The word needs to have the letters "J, U, G" (just the letters not the order) and at least one of these letters : G, L, E, R , S

So I can search a list for jugs, juggler, jugglers, juggles, etc.

Thanks

Comment: But your example `lugger` doesn't have all the `J`, `U` and `G`

Comment: Doesn't make sense. what is the difference between needs to have and atleast one of? And why is G in both?

Comment: ...your edited post includes `gurgle`, which also doesn't include `J`, `U`, and `G`...

Answer (score 2):

There is also a regex solution. But you should really give the language you are using because there can be other maybe better solutions for your task as @Quick Joe Smith wrote.

```
^(?=.*J)(?=.*U)(?=.*G)(?=.*[LERS]).*$
```

See on [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/FOkR71biXb)

Those `(?=)` are positive look aheads, they check if there is the character in the string but they don't match them. The `.*` at the end will then match your complete string.

You also need the modifier `i` to turn on ignorecase (case insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question does not lend itself to regular expressions very well at all. The pattern will end up a convoluted mess, and only get worse as you add more required characters.

The second part, however, is trivial:

```
m/[glers]/i
```

So I would suggest implementing a solution in two parts. This depends on your language:

## C# (using Linq)

```
var chars = "GJU"; // characters are sorted.
if (inputstring.ToUpper().Intersect(chars).OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEqual(chars)) {
    // do stuff if match.
}
```

## Perl (requires 5.10)

```
my @chars = sort split '', 'GJU'; # Transform into sorted array.
my %input = map{($_, 1)} split '', uc $inputstring; # stores unique chars from string.
if (@chars ~~ %input) { # Smart match performs hash key intersection.
    # Do stuff in here.
}
```

## Python

```
chars = set('jug')
input = set(inputstring)
if chars == (chars & input):
    # do something here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with one word at a time, try this:

```
boolean isMatch = s.matches(
  "(?i)^(?:J()|U()|G(?!.*G)()|[GLERS]()|\\w){4,}+$\\1\\2\\3\\4");
```

If you're searching for matches in a longer string:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "(?i)\\b(?:J()|U()|G(?!.*G)()|[GLERS]()|\\w){4,}+\\b\\1\\2\\3\\4");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String foundString = m.group();
}
```

Each time one of the first four alternatives - `J()`, `U()`, `G()` or `[GLERS]()` - matches something, the empty group following it "captures" nothing (i.e., an empty string).  When the end of the string is reached, each of the backreferences - `\1`, `\2`, etc. - tries to match the same thing its corresponding group matched: nothing again.

Obviously, that will always succeed; you can always match noting.  The trick is that the backreference won't even *try* to match if its corresponding group didn't participate in the match.  That is, if there's no `j` in the target string, the `()` in the `J()` alternative never gets involved.  When the regex engine processes the `\1` backreference later, it immediately reports failure because it knows that group hasn't participated in the match.

In this way, the empty groups act like a check boxes, and the backreferences make sure all the boxes have been checked.  There's one wrinkle, though.  Both the `G()` and `[GLERS]()` alternatives can match `g`; how do you make sure they both participate in the match when you need them to?  The first regex I tried,

```
"(?i)^(?:J()|U()|G()|[GLERS]()|\\w){4,}+$\\1\\2\\3\\4"
```

...failed to match the word "jugg" because the `G()` alternative was consuming both `g`'s; `[GLERS]()` never got a chance to participate.  So I added the negative lookahead - `(?!.*G)` - and now it only matches the *last* `g`.  If I had three alternatives that could match a `g`, I would have to add `(?!.*G.*G)` to the first one and `(?!.*G)` to the second.  But realistically, I probably would have switched to a different approach (probably one not involving regexes) well before I reached that point. ;)